# HIVE left join seems to return wrong results

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, left-join

I was inspecting some data mistery in our reports and I ran into the problem with left join.

I tried to rewrite my query into very simple schematic code. The first query returns 'foo' the second nothing. The only difference is only in the on condition and both selects should return zero lines. Thank you, Martin

```
SELECT 'foo'
FROM
  (SELECT
     'A' AS a,
     'B' AS b) X
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
     'C' AS a,
     'B' AS b) Y
    ON X.a = Y.a AND X.b = Y.b
WHERE Y.b IS NOT NULL;    

SELECT 'bar'
FROM
  (SELECT
     'A' AS a,
     'B' AS b) X
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT
     'C' AS a,
     'B' AS b) Y
    ON X.a = Y.a
WHERE Y.b IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: are you *sure* the first query returns a result?

Comment: unfortunately yes

Comment: if you are using a `where` clause with table b's non-null conditions, why don't you simply do a inner join?

Comment: yes, there are maybe several workarounds but it does not solve my problem. in fact there is problem in left join


select 'test', x.*, y.*, concat('TEST',y.b) as myst from
(select 'A' as a, 'B' as b) X
left join
(select 'C' as a, 'B' as b) Y
on X.a = Y.a and X.b = Y.b
where Y.b is not null
;
Returns:
test, a, b, null, null, TESTB